# How to create Marklogic App-Services port 8000 from Java in cluster

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I've set up a cluster using a slightly modified version of the MarkLogic Java API `com.marklogic.client.test.util.TestServerBootstrapper` to create the databases automatically along with the following http service

```
Admin       HTTP    Security        0.0.0.0 8001    no
HealthCheck HTTP    App-Services    0.0.0.0 7997    no
manage      HTTP    App-Services    0.0.0.0 8002    no
dbname      HTTP    dbname          0.0.0.0 8012    no
```

I've been able to create manually a copy of the default App-Services on port 8000 and adjust to use a different database and module database as

```
App-Services    HTTP    dbname  0.0.0.0 8013    no
```

I'm wondering how I would automatically create and tear down the that App-Services on port 8013 by modifying the java api client. Could you recommend documentation that I would need to read to accomplish that.

Thanks
Conteh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now, the Java Client API supports the [MarkLogic REST Client API](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/client), but not the [Management API](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/management).

From the [Java Application Developer's Guide](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/serverconfiguration#chapter):

> Note that you can only configure aspects of the underlying REST instance with the Java API. MarkLogic Server administration is not exposed in Java, so things such as creating indexes, creating users, creating databases, assigning roles to users, and so on must be done via the MarkLogic Admin Interface or other means (for example the Admin API or REST Management API).

If you want to do it from Java, you can send HTTP requests to the Management API. Good news: there's a community-driven project that will make this a lot easier. Take a look at @rjrudin's [ml-app-deployer](https://github.com/rjrudin/ml-app-deployer), a Java Client for the Management API. He's also written [a Gradle client](https://github.com/rjrudin/ml-gradle) for it that uses ml-app-deployer.